# Parse date with SimpleDateFormatter

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

Here's the code that should work, but does not:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String datata = "23:00:01 GMT, Sun Jul 28, 2012";
   String format = "HH:mm:ss zzz, EEE MMM dd, yyyy";

   try {
      DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
      Date parsedDate = inputFormat.parse(datata);
      System.out.println(parsedDate.toGMTString());
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

I'm getting a parse exception. I triple checked the patterns, I even wrote it one beneath the other, and I still get an exception. Help, anyone?

Comment: It works properly unless your locale doesn't support it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably because your default locale is not in english and the parser does not understand "Sun" and/or "Jul". Try using:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I spent 2 hours trying to format the date, I nearly lost my mind! :)